# no module named 'libreria'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keyboard

Estoy intentando programar un piano en python, para eso estoy usando las librerias: numpy, sounddevice y keyboard. La cuestión es que para que keyboard funcione, la tengo que ejecutar desde la terminal de ubuntu con el comando: sudo python3 piano.py pero las demás librerías(que ya funcionan  de por sí, si las ejecuto directamente desde el boton run de pycharm) me dan el siguiente error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' " ya sea con numpy o con sounddevice.
Que puedo hacer para que funcione??
Adjunto código:

```
    import keyboard as kb
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd
def frec(nota,octa):
    exp=(octa-4)*12+(nota-10)
    return 440*((2**(1/12))**exp)
def play(nota,octa):
    tiempo=500
    framerate = 44100
    frecuencia=frec(nota,octa)
    t=np.linspace(0,tiempo/1000,int(framerate * tiempo/1000))
    onda=np.sin(2 * np.pi * frecuencia *t)
    sd.play(onda,framerate)
    sd.wait()


while True:
    if kb.is_pressed("q"):
        play(3,4)
```

Comment: Hay distintas situaciones que pueden producir este error. Sin más detalles de tu entorno, puede ser cualquier cosa.

Comment: Básicamente instalé las librerías normalmente a través de la terminal de ubuntu (pip install "libreria"), numpy y sounddevice funcionan pero keyboard la tengo que ejecutar de otra manera porque larga el error "ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux" Soy bastante nuevo en python y linux, asique no tengo mucha idea...